# "You must login to ask a question" shown even on sites where anonymous asking is allowed

Tags: bug, asking-questions, login, wording

Open https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/login?returnurl=%2fquestions%2fask in incognito mode.
The page title reads: "You must login to ask a question," even though Arqade does not require users to log in to ask a question.

Comment: How did you arrive to that URL exactly? I clicked the "Ask Question" in http://gaming.stackexchange.com/ (in incognito mode) and it brought me to the ask new question page without a problem. If you mean it should redirect to the page, it's the same behavior as the Captcha - if you [browse directly](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/captcha) it will show, even though you're not a robot.

Comment: @sha trivially enough, open the ask page, then click on login.

Comment: Oh, the bug is the wording only. Retagged to prevent others from getting confused. (thought you meant we shouldn't get the login page)